# recompose withstate HOC added a header on a tabNavigator screen (expo snack)

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, tabnavigator, recompose, high-order-component

I recently added a withState HOC on a screen of my tabNavigator and I found the following problestrong textm :

[ScreenShot of the issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fGZIY.png)

Here is an expo snack to handle the issue:
https://snack.expo.io/@softhib/tabnavigator-and-recompose-withstate

The problem is on the HomeScreen.js at line 152.

Comment: I was going to help with this but your snack doesn't appear to have the problem specified?

Comment: Yes I finally found a solution !